# SingularityGS: How to code float-span variations with breakpoints?

Tags: singularitygs, breakpoint-sass

I have a float-span layout which contains a number of tiles in a 12 column grid. At breakpoint 600px I want this to display float-span(2) and at 1024px I want float-span(4).

I am finding that the smaller breakpoint layout displays as intended but the larger breakpoint layout is broken and appears to be inheriting the nth-child value from the lower breakpoint.

He is my gist http://sassmeister.com/gist/MrPaulDriver/8ac3bcf3e29c429b2efc

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

Having re-read a previous answer I now realise that it is necessary to define minimum and maximum media queries

See [Singularitygs: Mobile grid persisting all screen sizes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25349886/singularitygs-mobile-grid-persisting-all-screen-sizes)

Comment: You can accept your own answer. You can also make it better by mentioning that setting both min and max media queries prevent styles from leaking between media queries.